# How to limit a string character count in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send this text `Montréal-Pierre Elliott Trudeau International Airport, Montreal, QC, Canada` through a Ajax post to a php script. I'm getting a `500 (Internal Server Error)` when trying to send all the characters in the text.

When I tried `'Montréal-Pierre-Elliott-Trudeau-International'` by handcoding, it worked.

Here is my ajax script

```
$("#nomination-name").focus(function(){
        $.post(
            '/getlocation/'+$("#newLatitude").val()+"/"+$("#newLongitude").val()+"/"+'ok', // location of your php script
            { place: 'Montréal-Pierre-Elliott-Trudeau-International'}, // any data you want to send to the script
            function( data ){  // a function to deal with the returned information


    $(".flickr-images").remove();
            for(i=0;i<data.images.length;i++) {
                $("#images").append(data.images[i]);
            }
        });
});
```

Here is the server script:

```
public function getLocationImage($latitude, $longitude, $cc){

            //$place = 'Montreal, Pierre, Elliott, Trudeau, International, Airport';
            //GET THE IMAGES BASED ON THE LOCATION FROM FLICKR.
            $api_key = 'my_api_key';
            $text  = Input::get('place');
           // $text = 'airport';
            $lat = '&lat='.$latitude;
            $lon = '&lon='.$longitude;
            $perPage = 6;
            $url = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search';
            $url.= '&api_key='.$api_key;
            $url.= '&text='.$text;
//            $url.= $lat;
//            $url.= $lon;
            $url.= '&per_page='.$perPage;
            $url.= '&format=json';
            $url.= '&nojsoncallback=1';
            $response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
            $photo_array = $response->photos->photo;

            $count=0;
            foreach($photo_array as $single_photo){
                $size = 's';
                $size2='b';
                $photo_url = 'https://farm'.$single_photo->farm.'.staticflickr.com/'.$single_photo->server.'/'.$single_photo->id.'_'.$single_photo->secret.'_'.$size.'.'.'jpg';
                $photo_url_big = 'https://farm'.$single_photo->farm.'.staticflickr.com/'.$single_photo->server.'/'.$single_photo->id.'_'.$single_photo->secret.'_'.$size2.'.'.'jpg';

                $img[$count] = "<a href='$photo_url_big' target='_blank'><img class='flickr-images' title='' src='$photo_url' /></a>";
                $count++;
            }



            return Response::json(["success"=>"true", "images"=>$img]);


    }
```

I'm trying to remove the space and commas in a string and limit it's count to 20. I tried the following method but is not right.

```
$('#geocomplete').val().replace(/[, ]+/g, "-").substr(20, $('#geocomplete').val().replace(/[, ]+/g, "-").length)
```

Is this the right way?

Comment: `Internal server error` means there's a problem in the server script. Fix that instead of patching around it in the client.

Comment: I have no clue what that might be. Thats why I asked here.

Comment: Then post the server script. We can't tell anything from the client code.

Comment: To limit a string length to 20, use `.substr(0, 20)`. Your code is removing the first 20 characters.

Comment: Posted the script as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode the parameter:

```
$url.= '&text='.urlencode($text);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked with 15 characters. When I tried 20 characters, same error.

Comment: Have you checked the server's error log to see what error it's getting?

Comment: No, how do I check that? (I'm just a newbie)

Comment: I can see some errors in the console log. Is that it?

Comment: Go to the Network tab of the console, and look in the Response section of the AJAX call, to see if there are PHP error messages. If not, try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the beginning of your script so the errors will be sent to the client.

Comment: It says 
`{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Undefined variable: img","file":"C:\\wamp\\www\\nominator\\laravel\\app\\controllers\\FormController.php","line":72}}`

Comment: Is that the line `$img[$count] = "<a href=...`? You've never initialized the variable `$img` to hold an array.

Comment: if the Fickr API doesn't return anything, you'll never get into the `foreach` loop, so you won't get the error.

Comment: But I was getting images from he API request. Now when I tried with the 20 characters and array initialization, no error, no image.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = $('#geocomplete').val().substr(0,20); //get the first 20 characters
data.replace(/\s+/g, '-'); //replace all spaces with '-'
```

Comment: single line: `$('#geocomplete').val().substr(0,20).replace(/\s+/g, '-')`